# splitting 2 lists into a single list

Tags: python, list

i have two lists and my code to zip both lists as below

```
name=['paul','chris','omar','chen']
data=[('a'),('b','z'),('o'),('r')]

zip_data=zip(name,data)
for names,datas in zip_data:
    datas_str = ', '.join(datas)
    print(f'name={names} data={datas_str}')
```

the output is

```
name=paul data=a
name=chris data=b, z
name=omar data=o
name=chen data=r
```

but my desired output is

```
name=paul data=a
name=chris data=b
name=chris data=z
name=omar data=o
name=chen data=r
```

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading. Your purpose is not splitting the lists, but combining them.

Answer (score 2):

You can add another loop to loop through if there are multiple elements in the tuple.

```py
name=['paul','chris','omar','chen']
data=[('a'),('b','z'),('o'),('r')]

zip_data=zip(name,data)
for names,datas in zip_data:
  for dataName in datas: #extra loop
    print(f'name={names} data={dataName}')
```

Comment: I agree, I'll edit it to be a different name, thanks!

Comment: The datas_str variable is not necessary, its joining on a single character string which doesn’t do anything

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for i,j in zip(name, data):
    for char in j:
        print("name=",i,"data=",char)
```

output:

```
name= paul data= a
name= chris data= b
name= chris data= z
name= omar data= o
name= chen data= r
```